# clang/ARM assembly - Misinterpreted absolute branch

Tags: assembly, gcc, arm, clang

I am working on a project where code is linked into an existing, statically linked binary. Thus code like this with absolute branches is necessary:

```
.arm

.globl TestThunk
    TestThunk:
    mov     r0, #0
    b       0x01001234
```

gcc output:

```
00000000 <TestThunk>:
   0:   e3a00000    mov r0, #0
   4:   eafffffe    b   1001234 <*ABS*0x1001234>
```

with

```
arm-none-eabi-gcc -march=armv6k -mtune=mpcore -x assembler-with-cpp -c test.s -o test_gcc.o
```

clang output:

```
00000000 <TestThunk>:
   0:   e3a00000    mov r0, #0
   4:   ea40048d    b   1001240 <TestThunk+0x1001240>
```

with

```
clang --target=armv6k-none-eabihf -mcpu=mpcore -mtune=mpcore -x assembler-with-cpp -c test.s -o test_clang.o
```

As you can see gcc emits an absolute relocation, just like I want.
clang though emits a relocation relative to the object file itself, which is wrong.

Can I force clang to emit absolute relocations as well with specific compiler flags or assembler directives?

I am aware that I can create a linker script with symbols for the existing binary, but I don't want to do that for my existing code base.

Comment: I suppose this might be a bug in clang's builtin assembler.  You can use `-fno-integrated-as` to use the system's assembler instead of clang's assembler.

Comment: They are two different tools so by definition two different assembly languages, so both are correct as demonstrated.  (assembly language is defined by the tool not the target).  If you want to use gcc's assembly language then use gcc.

Comment: gcc's assembler sees that constant as an address, clangs sees that constant as an offset. both are correct within their assembly languages.

Comment: if you want an absolute address (which is how gcc interprets that value) then just branch to that address and not mess with assembly language nuances  ldr r3,=0x1001234 ; bx r3  or to be more portable   ldr r3,myadd ; bx r3 ; myadd: .word 0x1001234, with the appropriate adjustments for the assembler/assembly language (since this of course cannot be done without some assembly language nuances)

Comment: may I ask what arvm6 based mpcore this is?  I thought I was the only one that used an armv6 based mpcore (well the nds 2D has one). Note there is a bug with premature execution that was not documented by arm.  If this is really an armv6 based not an armv7 based mpcore then build using -march=armv4t to avoid falling into the trap (or use the mmu to protect what you can from fetching/reading from random addresses in the address space and insure the peripherals dont act on reads).

Comment: I wasn't aware that clang actually uses a different assembly language. Thought there was a standard for this. Interesting.
The "more portable" way you describe would emit two instructions though. Does clang not have a way to do this with a single one and without using a secondary register?

Comment: Also this is for the Nintendo 3ds cpu.

Comment: Hmm, yeah I thought only the 2D had it but the 3D does as well, or maybe when I went to go buy one I bought the 2D to save a few bucks...

Comment: assume every different tool has its own assembly language, including gcc vs gas (which are different)(gcc inline obviously yet another).  and you need to link not just look at the object,  the eafffffe is a branch to self placeholder so that means you need to link.  ea40048d,  40048d = 0x1001234/4 since the encoding is in units of instructions, so can be encoded at assemble time not link time.

Comment: If two tools happen to work with the same assembly language code, then thats a bonus.

Comment: you could also pass the parameters to thunk,  thunk(0,0x1001234);     .globl thunk ; thunk: bx r1

Comment: clang has nothing to do with the instruction set cant possibly have a single instruction for this the address is 32 bits and the instruction is 32 bits so you cant have a 32 bit immediate AND an opcode.  Granted they could have burned 1/4th of the instruction space with a word based absolute address sure, but why would they do that.  by making this a function that you call you are burning a number of instructions and perhaps stack locations, etc, depending.  you could pass the 0 and save an instruction or few

Comment: you can assemble this one function with gas, and the rest of your project with clang, then you are probably already linking with gnu anyway yes?  (so you have binutils already)

Comment: You have no arm/thumb issues here, the target is arm mode as well?

Comment: I am linking with clang actually. And I can't really make special cases for these branches because they are all over my existing code.

Comment: you built your own clang?  clangs linker is not built by default, perhaps you are using a toolchain built by someone?  (ld.lld)

Comment: either way you have binutils available as you have gcc, so you can make the object with gnu or maybe play around with things like #0x1001234 or dig into the clang sources to see i they have an option or other pseudo instruction.

Comment: I'm using regular clang together with lld. And I want to get rid of the toolchain that gcc came with.